# Set x,y goals and move the robot

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, move-base, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a robot on mecanum wheels and I installed on it a sensor able to provide x,y,z coordinates of its position at 10Hz. Morever, I placed four beacons in the four corners of the room in order to create a map.

I created a ROS node to publish `/odom` information:

```
rostopic echo /odom 
header: 
  seq: 3311
  stamp: 
    secs: 1584301150
    nsecs: 996412185
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 2.877
      y: 3.779
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: -0.018200000748
      y: 0.033900000155
      z: 0.00289999996312
      w: 0.999199986458
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.00457195335154
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
```

This is my TF tree:
[image: image description]

Then, I run `move_base`:

```
rosrun move_base move_base 
[ INFO] [1584298281.544211877]: global_costmap: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1584298281.550544640]:     Subscribed to Topics: 
[ INFO] [1584298281.556913732]: global_costmap: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [1584298281.598466274]: local_costmap: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1584298281.601248532]:     Subscribed to Topics: 
[ INFO] [1584298281.609893696]: local_costmap: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [1584298281.664725185]: Created local_planner base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS
[ INFO] [1584298281.672399153]: Sim period is set to 0.05
[ WARN] [1584298281.677701194]: Trajectory Rollout planner initialized with param meter_scoring not set. Set it to true to make your settings robust against changes of costmap resolution.
[ INFO] [1584298281.865343424]: Recovery behavior will clear layer 'obstacles'
[ INFO] [1584298281.872604788]: Recovery behavior will clear layer 'obstacles'
[ INFO] [1584298281.996921593]: odom received!
```

and I publish the first goal:

```
rostopic pub /move_base_simple/goal geometry_msgs/PoseStamped '{header: {stamp: now, frame_id: "base_link"}, pose: {position: {x: 1.0, y: 2.2, z: 0.0}, orientation: {w: 1.0}}}'
```

I can see the robot IMMEDIATELY change its position in RVIZ, but if I read the `cmd_vel` topic, I always find ZERO values.
Shouldn't `move_base` update the `cmd_vel` topic to send the values to a robot controller?

I just get this from `cmd_vel`:

```
linear: 
  x: -0.1
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
---
linear: 
  x: -0.1
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346720/set-x,y-goals-and-move-the-robot/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2020-03-14

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-14**:
So is this related to #q340495?

If so, it would be nice to post a final answer/comment there so future readers know what you eventually ended up using.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-03-14**:
It is the same project, but my previous topic is still open because I didnt find a correct solution, yet. I just want to explore this solution and to do so I need to know how to use the waypoint with this method. This topic it is just a branch of the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Move base in ROS1 or Navigation in ROS2 will do this for you.

There is no requirement of a "well-defined world", though that is as you have found a common application of it. If you are able to produce a global localization estimate, odometry, and some sensor data, you can make move base work for you.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-03-14**:
I edited my first topic by adding more information. I created a map and displayed it in RVIZ, now the robot related to "my_frame" is able to move inside the map. However, I cannot make it move  towards waypoints with move_base. What should I do to solve this?

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-03-14**:
I have no sensors, I just have the beacon that gives me the robot coordinates.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-03-14**:
"it doesn't move" doesn't help in debugging -- I'd recommend looking at any warnings or errors and addressing them. There are a variety of resources for properly configuring the navigation stack you should explore

http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide

http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-03-14**:
Thank you for your answer. I have no range sensor, no encoders and no Odom frame. I just have my_frame which is the frame of the beacon  installed on the robot. I have a transform from my_frame to base_link and my_frame to map. When I play the rosbag, i see my_frame moving in rviz. If i try to set a goal, nothing happens and if i try to rostopic echo cmd_vel, it says that no messages can be displayed.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-03-14**:
I added more information after EDIT2 in the main topic. However, /cmd_vel, /odom and other topics are always not enabled since I get: `WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active. Is /clock being published?`

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-03-15**:
@stevemacenski In the navigation tutorial, it says `The navigation stack uses information from sensors to avoid obstacles in the world, it assumes that these sensors are publishing either sensor_msgs/LaserScan or sensor_msgs/PointCloud messages over ROS.` but I have no laser! I just have the beacon installed on the robot and I need to move the robot towards a goal. Can't I use the move_base, then?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-15**:
Thing is, you're trying to use `move_base` for something which is not a standard configuration. You may not have the regular sensors, but as @stevemacenski already notes, you have something perhaps even better: an oracle which provides you with the absolute pose of your `base_link` (or at least, I'm assuming this, it's probably the pose of your tranceiver, but that's just a single transform away from `base_link`).

You'll need to make sure to provide the appropriate data to the nodes that expect it. At the very least, convert whatever your tranceiver outputs to (fi) a TF frame. Probably (but @stevemacenski correct me if/when wrong), broadcasting a transform between `map` and `base_link` directly, as you have no odom (or perfect odom).

`move_base` should be able to work with that.

One thing I don't understand though: if you have no sensors that will tell you anything about "the world", why bother with `move_base` at all? It sounds like a very heavy weight way ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-15**:
.. to get at a 2.5D position controller for your platform.

Wouldn't a simple position controller be sufficient?

> but I have no laser!

please stop fussing about not having a laser and consider things a bit more abstractly.

Take a step back and consider what's really important: the current pose of your `base_link`, the desired pose and any obstacles in between. If there are no obstacles, you don't care about that bit. So this leaves: current pose, desired pose. As long as you can feed `move_base` the current pose, it will be able to calculate `Twist`s that will try to minise `desired_pose - current_pose` (ie: steer your `base_link` towards the desired pose).

But again: if that's all your interested in then even though `move_base` can certainly do this, I'm still not sure whether it's not a bit overkill.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-03-15**:
Thank you again for your support! I already have a tf `rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  my_frame base_link 1` and I set goals in this way: `rostopic pub /move_base_simple/goal geometry_msgs/PoseStamped '{header: {stamp: now, frame_id: "map"}, pose: {position: {x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0}, orientation: {w: 1.0}}}'` but the 'cmd_vel`topic is always blank. I could publish a`/odom` since the beacon always outputs the x,y,z coordinates in meters plus the quaternion for the orientation. I do not care about obstacles, I just need to make the robot go straight from goal A and goal B. If I'm not forced to use move_base, how can I make the robot move towards a x,y point in a easier way?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-15**:
What is `my_frame`? Is `my_frame` broadcast by a node which takes the output of your "beacon driver" and converts it to a `Transform`?

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-03-15**:
I updated my first topic by adding the output of the node that contains the my_frame coordinates. I hope this helps

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-15**:
A `VisualisationMarker` is not a TF transform.

`move_base` is going to need TF to know where your `base_link` is.

If you don't have a node which takes in the output from your tranceiver and broadcasts it as a TF transform, I would recommend you create one.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-03-15**:
can you suggest me a tutorial, please? I'm trying to create a node that publishes odometry data for `base_link`, is this a good solution? I'm following this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-15**:
That tutorial would cover it.

You probably don't absolutely need the `Odometry` publisher, but it doesn't hurt.

And you'd get your data from a `Subscriber` to the tranceiver's publications of course.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-03-15**:
I changed my main topic to reflect the updates. Now, the odom topic works fine and the move_base moves the robot in RVIZ, but the `cmd_vel` reports always ZERO values. Why does this happen?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-03-16**:
Hi,

It sounds like you're getting on the right track, but frankly, I don't have the cycles to help specifically go through every failure mode or issue that may arise from your application. I can tell you from first hand knowledge I've setup the navigation stack to work with a robot operating in an external frame source (motion capture). Its possible, but its going to require some legwork on your part to read the documentation, try to understand the purpose and roll of the components, and make reasonable decisions to get everything to work.

There is no requirement that anything in particular exists for the navigation stack beyond some source of odometry, some source of global positioning, and some sensors if you're not operating in a vacuum (which it seems you are). Please consult the documentation above and the plethora of examples online.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-03-16**:
Just few questions: Does `move_base` already integrate the planner or do I need to configure one to make it work with `move_base`? Moreover, do I need to directly publish a `move_base/feedback` with the current position? Moreover, when I set a new `goal`, the frame moves in RVIZ accordingly, but the `/odom` odometry topic doesn't change its coordinates! So I think there is something wrong and that's for this reason that `cmd_vel` does not provide correct values but always ZERO.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-16**:\

> I changed my main topic to reflect the updates

Please don't do this. All comments and answer(s) that were there before your update now don't make sense / are out-of-sync.

*Append* to your original question text. Structure it with `Edit` sections.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-16**:
re: your TF tree: why are you still publishing all these frames using a `static_transform_publisher` (STP)?

The whole idea is that you publish a transform based on the data your (global) positioning system is giving you. An STP cannot do this as it does not change, ever. You've essentially locked your robot into a single location, which is not what you'd want.

Just to clarify: `odom` is a separate topic. Unless there is a node taking in `Odometry` messages and somehow converting those to a TF frame (perhaps via sensor fusion, like `robot_localization` does), having an `Odometry` publisher will not be sufficient -- the TF side will be missing. `move_base` "only" looks at TF (not entirely true, but having the correct -- and working -- TF structure is very important).

From #q346761 it would appear you also have a TF broadcaster for the global position, so I'm not sure why you included the STPs.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-03-16**:
As you said, I should not use the statis transform, that was an error and I corrected it; in effect, I already have a transform published by the `/odom` node. So, the TF between odom and base link is defined, but how can I definy a dynamic TF between `map` and `odom`? I do not have `AMCL` or `gmapping` (they even can't work since i have no laser) so how can I publish a TF for `map` and `odom`? I load the map with `map_server`. I can set `map` to be coincident with `odom` with a static TF, but I do not know if it can be OK.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-03-16**:
After having followed the [navigation tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup), I created global and local `costmaps`, added the `AMCL` to my launch file, but when I launch `move_base`, when I try to send  a goal, it says that `No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1584395127.621761 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.` But obviously I have no laser sensor and my map is already created and I load it with `map_server`, I have no obstacles in it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-17**:
I really don't understand why you start adding AMCL to this setup:

1. you have no sensor for AMCL to use
2. you already have a global localisation oracle available

Remove all of it.

You don't need a "dynamic TF between `map` and `odom`" necessarily. In the end, the transform `map->base_link` is needed. `odom` is added to that normally to account for drift in localisation approaches which depend on things like (noisy) odometry from wheel encoders, or laser scan matching, etc.

You don't have any of that (or: we'll assume the MarvelMind stuff provides a good global, absolute pose estimate).

Your "odom node" (which is not a good name btw) should probably publish either the `map->odom` or the `odom->base_link` transform. @stevemacenski: which one would make more sense?

Whichever TF it ends up publishing: use STP to broadcast an identity one for the other.

At this point TF should be setup.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-17**:
If you don't want to do this, take a look at [wiki/fake_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/fake_localization), which takes in `nav_msgs/Odometry` and broadcasting it as a `Transform`. Essentially imitating AMCL.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-03-17**:
You still require a odom frame. I’d recommend having it publish odom at base link and just have an identity transform from map to odom if you really dont have wheel odometry, which I sort of doubt.

There’s going to be some trial and error if you don’t sit down and try to read documentation and code to fully understand. This part is no different.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-17**:
If there is already a global pose available through other means, would adding wheel odometry still be valuable?

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-03-17**:
I do not have wheel odometry, however, at the moment, after read all the documentation, I'm using an identity TF `map->odom` and it works, I had to define global and local costmaps and to add a local planner for holonomic robots and now it seems to work, I still have to test it better and I'm going to do it in the next hours, today. I do not like to have an identity TF between `map` and `odom`, honestly, but I didn't find any other suitable solution.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-03-17**:
@gvdhoorn, yes it would be. It adds smoothing characteristics and projected updates between refresh cycles. You will only know your position at 10hz vs if you had odometry and accessed the pose through TF, you could have accurate updates at up to 1kHz. Maybe not required, but certainly part of a balanced breakfast.

I don't know why you don't like the identity transform, its a legitimate thing to do since you have global knowledge and no other odometry. Really, you should think of your external sensor as an external form of odometry not a word-from-god position.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-03-17**:
If you have things working well enough, can you mark this answer as correct to get off the unanswered queue?

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-03-17**:
I will in few hours, i'm just trying to be sure that everything is OK.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2020-03-21**:
I marked the question as solved since move_base is surely the package I need. I'm opening a new question since I'm still having problems not strictly related to this question. Thank you for all your support.